# Is it possible to have a transparent 'sea area' in leaflet, tilemap from openstreetmap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

> [image: My Current Code]

[image: The result]

How can I make the sea to be transparant like a .png image ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You are using the openstreetmap titles which can't modified. Even with mapbox which you can configure the colors it can't be transparent. I mean it does transparent but the layer in back is the land. https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/moshfeu/cl09d75l0000z15swohtjbakj.html?title=view&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibW9zaGZldSIsImEiOiJjajhvdGR0MzMwN3R1MzJyem8wcWR6djNzIn0.Qf3UZSXWeBPQ2F2CUPZgIA&zoomwheel=true&fresh=true#1.21/-33.8/34.1. [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8300852/863110)